# Making tappable HTML div for iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, webkit

In my HTML code, I got a `<div>`. When the user taps anywhere inside that div, I'd like to alter various properties, like text size and background color. To me, this sounds a lot like creating two CSS styles for each state sounds like it should work, so I created the following CSS:

```
div.tappable {
   background-color: red;
   font-size: 10pt;
}

div.tappable:active {
   background-color: green;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

For some reason, the `:active` style is never used. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this blog posting will be a good start to explaining how to track the events in moble safari and  create the ui you are looking for

[Touching and Gesturing on the iPhone](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` selector is triggered for the duration in which the element is being pressed.  However, on an iPhone, because of the nature of the touch screen, Mobile Safari doesn't use the `:active` selector.

To clarify, did you want to alter the properties *while* the user is pressing down on the div, or alter the properties *after* the user taps on the div?

Comment: I want to alter the properties while the user is pressing down.